# Android Screen In virtualbox Rotate 90 CCW?

Tags: screen, android-emulator, virtualbox

I install Android 4.4 x86 on virtualbox in windows 8.1
That was Ok But when I install my first app pheed on it .
now when I run pheed app my screen rotate 90 ccw like as image .
[image]
I try some stakoverflow post about android screen landscape and portrait but none of them help me .
I tried some shortcut key like as :

> ctrl+f9
>   ctrl+f10
>   ctrl+f11
>   ctrl+f12
>   Or press them twice in lessthen a second but none of theme fix it ?!!
>   have any idea to fix it ?

Comment: Have you tried to lock the screen orientation before running Pheed?

Comment: how do I must to do it in virtualbox  ?

Comment: The screen orientation is not controlled by VirtualBox - VirtualBox is just doing what Android is telling it to do. I'm not sure which version of Android you're running, but you will probably find the Android setting in Settings->Accessibility->Auto-rotate screen. Make sure this is unchecked.  Note that I didn't post this as an answer because I've had trouble like this in the past and, depending on the app, it may or may not work. I'm not familiar with Pheed.

Comment: Ohh auto rotation is off now dear ...there are a lot of my app going to this shape , this is not because of pheed , instagram , facebook , twitter and some more all rotating while running them

Answer (score 12):

There are some [hotkeys listed for ICS](http://android-x86.sceners.org/en/?p=562), which hopefully still work with Kitkat:

> **Rotating the screen: (to get that operate we must to have activated “Auto-rotate screen”)**
>
> - **Press F12** two times in less than 2 seconds = Rotate **90º to the LEFT.**
> - **Press F11**  two times in less than 2 seconds = Rotate **90º to the RiGHT.**
> - **Press F10** two times in less than 2 seconds = **Rotate 180º.**
> - **Press F9**   two times in less than 2 seconds = Normal view **0/360º.**

So I'd say try hitting <kbd>F11</kbd> twice should solve your issue – after activating screen-rotation.

Comment: does not help with applications that force particular orientation :-(

Comment: blame the corresponding devs, @PhilippMunin – nothing we can do about it, sorry.

Comment: I just installed Smart Rotate app from google play and it works fine now. This should be and answer for this question

Comment: @PhilippMunin then why not post it as answer, giving some additional details on how to achieve the goal with it?