# Prevent Screen from rotating in Android VM

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, virtualbox

Using VirtualBox, I have created a Virtual Android.  My problem is that certain apps will rotate the screen, but virtual box doesn't flip.

Here is my guide:

http://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/

How do I either rotate the screen or keep it from rotating?

I tried disabling the "Auto Rotate Screen" option, but there are some apps that force the screen rotation.

Comment: Have you considered this answer: [Android Screen In virtualbox Rotate 90 CCW?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/81979)

Comment: Thanks for the link!  That doesn't prevent the rotation, but at least I can rotate it.

Comment: Problem with rotating it is that the Android when loaded in VirtualBox doesn't get a "vertical" position.  So I want to use an app that requires a vertical position and can't get it that way.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe apps listed in my answer can help you out: [how do I enable 180 degree screen rotation on Moto G (3rd gen)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/124218)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I wasn't able to make the rotation NOT happen in Android on VirtualBox, but I found another virtual platform for Android called [Andyroid](http://www.andyroid.net/).  Andyroid still provides Android within a virtual machine, AND the Andyroid wrapper provides methods of rotating the Android for you (not the same as using the keyboard commands in Virtual Box).  So I didn't solve the very problem, but I solved the situation.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem when trying to run QQ on Android 4.4 running in VirtualBox. F9-F12 were ineffective as soon as QQ started. The app "Ultimate Rotation Control" does the trick but does not resize the QQ window. So part of it gets to lie out of the virtual screen. Finally, I ended up redefining the screen size of the virtual Android to 360x640 (portrait) as described [here](https://4sysops.com/archives/change-the-screen-resolution-of-an-android-virtualbox-vm/). It seems that QQ detects which side of the screen is longer and rotates according to this. So if you start with a portrait aspect ratio it will not rotate sideways. I do not about pheed, but guess it operates the same way.